# Octoprint plugin development - dynamically generated "plugin settings page" + button click handle

Tags: python, plugins, jinja2, octoprint

I have problem with octoprint plugin development. I need show some dynamic generated data by python backend on setting/plugins/myPluginPage. I can create static page with some link to some settings (I don't know how it works, but it works good), but I can't find how to show data generated by python script in UI. Maybe I will need add some refresh button for this data, is there some way to do that? 
Sorry for my bad english and thank you for your replies.